# How to block only Yandex bot using robots.txt

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, robots.txt, yandex

Can you show me how `robots.txt` will look when I block only Yandex bot?

I want to allow Googlebot and block Yandex bot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many "Yandex bots". If you want to block *all* the Yandex bots then:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /
```

However, if you only want to block the main indexing "YandexBot" then:

```
User-agent: YandexBot
Disallow: /
```

Source:
https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml

You don't need to do anything for Googlebot (or any other bot) if you want the other bots to crawl your site, since *allow* (crawling) is the default action.

Comment: Yeah, I generally use robots.txt to prevent something, because by default all bots are allowed to crawl. For example wikipedia site blocking Google-ads bot(Mediapartners-Google*), because they are not using any ads. So it helps them to save some bandwidth.

Comment: ok so if i want block all yandex bot, i need add in robots.txt this:

User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: / ?

Comment: @nikola99 Yes, that should do it.